# insert <ul></ul into few <li>s with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is sample code:

```
<ul id="ul-1" class="ul">
    <li class="group">A</li>
    <li class="group">B</li>
    <li id="c1" class="group c">C1</li>
    <li id="c2" class="group c">C2</li>
    <li id="c3" class="group c">C3</li>
</ul>
```

Here is what I want to achieve with jQuery 1.4:

```
<ul id="ul-1" class="ul">
    <li class="group">A</li>
    <li class="group">B</li>
    <ul class="group-c">
          <li id="c1" class="group c">C1</li>
          <li id="c2" class="group c">C2</li>
          <li id="c3" class="group c">C3</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Basically I want to  group some of the list items into another group.

Here what's I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         $("#c1").insertBefore("<ul class='group-c'>");
         $("#c3").insertAfter("</ul>");
     });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         $("#c1").insertBefore("<li class='group-c'>");
         $("#c3").insertAfter("</li>");
     });
</script>
```

Comment: A) What have you tried? and B) The output you desire is invalid HTML (a ul can't be a child of another ul)

Comment: I want to regroup some of the <li>s. It should be possible...?

Comment: Of course it's possible. But we don't take requests. You need to demonstrate some effort first.

Comment: Also if you google something like `wrap li in ul` you would get alot of answer that could help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the answer to your question:

```
$('li.group.c').wrapAll("<ul class='group-c'></ul>");
```

BUT that would resolve in some invalid `html` since the `ul` cannot be a direct child of another `ul` so you have to use this:

```
$('li.group.c').wrapAll("<li class='group-c'>C<ul></ul><li>");
```

**Demo**

```js
$('li.group.c').wrapAll("<li class='group-c'>C<ul></ul><li>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul-1" class="ul">
    <li class="group">A</li>
    <li class="group">B</li>
    <li id="c1" class="group c">C1</li>
    <li id="c2" class="group c">C2</li>
    <li id="c3" class="group c">C3</li>
</ul>
```